# How to restore my Copay / BitPay Wallet?

Tags: copay

I started using Copay in 2015 and got some Bitcoins. Sold some coins, and then stop use the app. Now Bitcoin price is up again, and try to reach my Wallet but I can not import, though I  know the 12 word. What I am doing wrong? This is my address I get originally my payment:

1DpmSrg9Bur2VhiMqEu4gYnA28gaM7ZVjp

I tried recover: https://bitpay.github.io/copay-recovery/

No success. I tried different `Addres Gap`, 40, 80, 100, 120: No success.
I tried import with different derivation path listed here, no success: https://walletsrecovery.org

Do you have any idea more?

Seems cold paper based wallet are still more secure, right?
Do you know, is it any process I can detect `Derivation Path` from existing address, and transaction started on it?

---

[EDIT]

Here is the logs of transactions:

[image]

Comment: You can download the Bitpay wallet and enter your 12-word phrase?

Comment: I can enter and import, but it says it has 0 dollar with my 12-word. If I change `Derivation Path`, some "old" ones, it says: `We couldn't found your wallet!" There are no record of your wallet on our servers. If you are importing BIP44 compatible..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I tried recover: https://bitpay.github.io/copay-recovery/ [...] No success.**

I don't know why you put your recovery phase into a website. That seems a very risky thing to have done. The distinction between github.com and github.io is also something I'd find a concern that would make me hesitate.

A message like `There are no record of your wallet on our servers.` makes it sound like recovery of a custodial wallet but wasn't the Copay wallet non-custodial?

I would worry that having typed my recovery phrase into a website, someone will have already stolen any money.

---

What I would have done is download the Bitpay wallet app from the Google play store (after checking very carefully that the app authors are listed as Bitpay) and use that software's wallet "recovery" features. I would not use "import".

If the balance showed zero, I would check for recent transactions moving the money away.

Comment: Hi! Yes, Copay wallet is non-custodial. Strange though I see many transaction between transaction I triggered in person. But anyway my holding are untouched in the blockchain for some years. I just can not access it, even though I have the 12-word.

Comment: I attached a screen shot. Would you check it? Still around 2.5 BTC is unreachable, but I do not know how to get a private key from my 12-word or something to do a withdrawal.